# CSS styles are not being applied in styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am following [Caveat](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#caveat) guide, but the CSS styles are not being applied in `A` styled component. The `console.log()` statement does not execute either.

I can see the rendered HTML element of the component via web inspector:

```html
<div class="sc-gueYoa iEvPOn">Text</div>
```

The `style` tag also be injected into the document.

```html
<style data-styled="active" data-styled-version="5.3.9">.iEvPOn .sc-beqWaB{font-size:18px;color:red;}</style>
```

As you can see, the classname are not totally matched. `sc-gueYoa` classname does not match the `sc-beqWaB`. I think this is the reason.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const A = ({ children, ...rest }: React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div">) => {
  console.log("rest: ", rest);
  return <div {...rest}>This is A {children}</div>;
};

const StyledA = styled(A)``;

const B = styled.div`
  ${StyledA} {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <B>Text</B>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76867075-r6yg98)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A and StyledA have been crafted by you.
Inside your App's JSX, you're not using StyledA even though you intend to style it inside of B. Instead, you're resorting to using B.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const A = ({ children, ...rest }: React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"div">) => {
  console.log("rest: ", rest);
  return <div {...rest}>This is A {children}</div>;
};

const StyledA = styled(A)``;

const B = styled.div`
  ${StyledA} {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: red;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <B>
        <StyledA>Text</StyledA> {/* Use StyledA inside B */}
      </B>
    </div>
  );
}
```